# Can I get index directly from pointer of vector element in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have a big vector container that holds around 300.000 object. Also I have pointers to these objects.

Are there any fast way to get index of object in vector with using pointer?

Comment: Add some code in order to clarify. Are you talking about `std::vector` or a old-school array?

Comment: Well, probably not what you want to hear as an answer... Assuming you are talking about std::vector - keeping pointers is very error prone. It is much better to keep indices. The reason is that the pointers (or iterators) become invalid anytime the vector is reallocated, which is done automatically if you push in some elements above the reserved size. Or are you 110 % sure that the vector will not grow after the pointers are determined? This seems to be a design flaw which will probably bite you in the future if not now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since vectors are organized sequentially, you can get an index by subtracting pointer to initial element from the pointer to element in question:

```
std::vector<MyObject> vect;
MyObject *ptrX = ... // Pointer to element in question
ptrdiff_t index = ptrX - &vect[0];
```

Comment: That assumes not evil overload for `operator&`. `std::addressof` solves that (but not sure that it doesn't introduce UB for empty vector then...).

Answer (score 2):

[Iterator header](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/) should be useful in that case.

Let's assume you have something like:

```
using Vector = std::vector<Foo>;
using Iterator = Vector::iterator;

Vector big_vector;
```

And now your have an iterator to an object:

```
Iterator p_obj = get_Theobj(big_vector);
```

The the index could be easily get with [distance](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/distance/):

```
auto index = std::distance(big_vector.begin(), p_obj);
// Note: index's type is a `difference_type` aka ptrdiff_t (usually signed integer).
```

The powerful of using that approach is the versatility. Indeed, it works with "C-like vector", `std::array`, `std::list`, as well.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `std::distance`

```
 std::vector<Object> objects = /*..*/;
 const Object *p = /* object[i] */;
 std::ptrdiff_t index = std::distance(objects.data(), p);
 // Now index == i.
```

Comment: That would compare every element in `myObjects` so work in linear time.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Pointers meet *RandomAccessIterator* requirements, so it is constant time.

Comment: @Jarod42 You've just copy my answer :P

Comment: @BiagioFesta: You answer for iterator, I answer for pointers. (And I answer before to see your).

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of good answers here. Combining them together, here's a little library suite which allows computation of the index of an item by either pointer or reference.

As an added bonus, the caller may optionally supply a policy object, to be enacted if the element is not in the container.

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>


struct exception_policy
{
    [[noreturn]]
    std::size_t out_of_range() const
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("index_of_element");
    }
};

struct assertion_policy
{
    std::size_t out_of_range() const
    {
        assert(!"out of range");
        return _fallback.out_of_range();
    }

    exception_policy _fallback {};
};

struct zero_policy
{
    std::size_t out_of_range() const
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

template<class T, class A, class Policy = exception_policy>
std::size_t index_of_element(std::vector<T, A> const& vec,
                             typename std::vector<T, A>::const_pointer pitem,
                             Policy policy = Policy{})
{
    auto pbegin = vec.data();
    auto pend = pbegin + vec.size();
    if (pitem < pbegin or pitem >= pend)
    {
        return policy.out_of_range();
    }
    else
    {
        return std::distance(pbegin, pitem);
    }
}

template<class T, class A, class Policy = exception_policy>
std::size_t index_of_element(std::vector<T, A> const& vec,
                      typename std::vector<T, A>::const_reference item, Policy policy = Policy{})
{
    return index_of_element(vec, std::addressof(item), policy);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    auto px = std::addressof(v[5]);
    auto& rx = *px;

    try {
        // use default policy of throwing out_of_range...
        auto i = index_of_element(v, rx);
        assert(i == 5);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        assert(!"should not throw");
    }

    try {
        auto i = index_of_element(v, px);
        assert(i == 5);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        assert(!"should not throw");
    }

    auto py = v.data() + 1000;  // out of bounds
    try {
        auto i = index_of_element(v, py);
        assert(!"should have thrown");
    }
    catch(std::out_of_range const& e)
    {
        // success
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        assert(!"should not throw this");
    }

    // specify a custom policy
    auto i = index_of_element(v, ry, zero_policy());
    assert(i == 0);    
}
```

Comment: @Jarod42 that is true officially, but I'll bet you £20 that on your system it yields a reference to an object located outside the vector's allocated data. This is a test fixture. I could easily have said (v.data() + 1000), but I don't think it would have been as expressive. The point (I hope) is that the function `index_of_element()` catches out_of_bounds elements (by address, so defined behaviour) and treats them with the policy.

Comment: ...and typo fixed so that the comparison correctly fails when `addressof(item) == addressof(*v.end())`

Answer (score 0):

```
int getIndex(Object* pObject) {return pObject - &(my_vewctor[0]);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming C++11 at least:

You have some `class Myclass;` (hopefully a rather small one, since you have many instances of it).

You have some variable `std::vector<Myclass> bigvec;` and it is big enough so could have about half a million objects.

You have some valid pointer `Myclass* ptr;` and it could point inside an object from `bigvec`.

You might get its index in `bigvec` in `int ix;` (or better yet `size_t ix;`) using

```
if (ptr >= bigvec.data() && ptr < bigvec.data() + bigvec.size())
  ix = ptr - bigvec.data();
```

However, be aware that you could have made *copies* of `Myclass` (e.g. thru assignment, passing by value some argument, etc...), and then a pointer to such a copy won't be in `bigvec`

Comment: If I'm not wrong, this would work if you deal with a `std::vector<Myclass*>`, not with `std::vector<Myclass>`

Comment: On the contrary, it won't work with a vector of pointers. You need a vector of objects.

Comment: don't you need to take account of sizeof(MyClass)? (and yes, it does not work for a vector of pointer neither)

Comment: No, pointer arithmetic is always done in increment of object sizes (both in C or C++).