# How to modernize a parallel C-style matrix-vector multiplication implementation using e.g. `std::transform`?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, c++17, std

I am trying to adapt my programming practices with more modern approaches that leverage STL containers, algorithms, execution-policies, etc.

I developed a small test to experiment with modernizing my C-style implementation of a basic matrix-vector multiplication: `C[N] = A[N,M] * B[N]`, which is parallelized with OpenMP. In here, follows the high-level main-program where I set the parameters of the problem, initialize the vectors with some random values, and then perform the matrix-vector multiplication in two different approaches.

```
int main(){

    size_t N(9), M(5);

    std::vector<double> A(N*M), B(M), C(N);

    fill_random(A, 1.0, 1.0); // if min==max the vector is filled with that particular value, otherwise, it's randomly sampled with values in the range [min,max]
    fill_random(B, 1.0, 1.0);

// Run for-loop based routine (parallel OpenMP)
    std::fill(C.begin(), C.end(), 0.0);
    bool err_for = run_for_loop_based_solution(A, B, C, N, M);
    if(!err_for)
        std::cout << "For-loop solution executed successfully!" << std::endl;

    std::for_each(C.begin(), C.end(), [](double x){
        std::cout << x << " ";
    });
    std::cout << std::endl;

// Run transform-based solution 
    std::fill(C.begin(), C.end(), 0.0);
    bool err_task = run_transform_based_based_solution(A, B, C, N, M);
    if(!err_task)
        std::cout << "Transform-based solution executed successfully!" << std::endl;

    std::for_each(C.begin(), C.end(), [](double x){
    std::cout << x << " ";
    });
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Now, lets go to the two implementations!

The reference implementation, namely `run_for_loop_based_solution(A, B, C, N, M);` is developed using a C-style implementation based on for-loops. The computation is parallelized with OpenMP threads in such a way that each thread calculates the value of one or more elements of the output vector `C[N]`. Simple!

```
template<typename T>
bool run_for_loop_based_solution(std::vector<T> &A, std::vector<T> &B, std::vector<T> &C, size_t N, size_t M)
{
    if (A.size() != N*M) return 1;
    if (B.size() != M) return 1;
    if (C.size() != N) return 1;

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(size_t i=0; i<N; ++i)
        for(size_t j=0; j<M; ++j)
            C[i] += A[i*M + j] * B[j];
    
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I want to develop an implementation using `std::transform`, namely `run_transform_based_based_solution(A, B, C, N, M);`, which provides the option to select an execution policy to enable parallelism, e.g. `std::execution::par`. Something like this:

```
template<typename T>
bool run_transform_based_based_solution(std::vector<T> &A, std::vector<T> &B, std::vector<T> &C, size_t N, size_t M)
{
    if (A.size() != N*M) return 1;
    if (B.size() != M) return 1;
    if (C.size() != N) return 1;

    // std::transform(std::execution::par, C.begin(), C.end(), C.begin(), [&](double x){
    //     return ...  
    // });

    return 0;
}
```

I struggle at this point because I cannot understand how to propagate within the body of `std::transform` the indices or the ranges that are associated with the computation of each element. Is it possible to do it following this approach(?), or maybe is there an alternative, other than `std::transform` approach?

*NOTE:*
To run the code just include the above code-snippets in a single `main.cpp` file and compile using `-std==c++17`. Also, include the following snippet in the beginning:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <execution>

// fill a std::vector with random values in the range [min, max]. if min==max the vector is filled with that particular value.
template<typename T>
void fill_random(std::vector<T> &v, T min, T max){
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<T> dist(min, max);
    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), [&](T x){
        return dist(gen);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the index, you can use the method of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39142203/8649091)

```cpp
    std::transform(std::execution::par, C.begin(), C.end(), C.begin(),
        [&A, &B, &C, M](T& i) -> T {
            auto index = &i - &C[0]; // Calculate the row index
            return std::inner_product(A.begin() + index * M, A.begin() + (index + 1) * M, B.begin(), i);
    });
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/r73dMGr4r)

Comment: Thanks, seems to work fine! I will need to dive into the details of this snippet because this implementation is out of my sphere... A question: what does `-> T` serve in this case? I see that the code compiles either with or without it!

Comment: Its *trailing-return-type* of a lambda. It's totally fine here without it.

Comment: I see, it's the return-type of the inner-product

Answer (score 0):

The calculation for each `C[i]` is a [`std::inner_product`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inner_product) of a subrange of `A` with `B`. If you have a [chunk view](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/structranges_1_1views_1_1chunk__fn.html), then it's fairly simple:

```
template<typename T, typename Execution>
bool run_transform_based_based_solution(Execution e, std::vector<T> &A, std::vector<T> &B, std::vector<T> &C, size_t N, size_t M)
{
    if (A.size() != N*M) return 1;
    if (B.size() != M) return 1;
    if (C.size() != N) return 1;

    const chunks = ranges::views::chunk(A, M);

    std::transform(e, chunks.begin(), chunks.end(), C.begin(), [e, &B](auto chunk){ 
        return std::inner_product(e, chunk.begin(), chunk.end(), B.begin(), B.end());
    });

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. I tried it but it does not compile though! First, there should be `const auto` before chunks. Then, needs `std::` before ranges. However, even with these changes it does not compile because it does not recognise `chunks`. That is the related error I get `error: ‘chunk’ is not a member of ‘std::ranges::views’`

Comment: My compiler and OS info are: `g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0`

Comment: @AndreasHadjigeorgiou no, `chunk` is from the ranges v3 library, not all of which was standardised